# Load facebook commentbox without comments

Tags: facebook, comments

I will try to make it short. I need to implement the Facebook Commentbox in my page so that only the form is loaded in the iframe but not the posts. Posts will be displayed in an other way trough the facebook API.

I tried data-num-posts="0" but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to display the form in the facebok iframe without the posts or should I do my own form with a "Publish to my wall" checkbox using the Graph API ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the commentbox in a div, apply `style="overflow:hidden;"` to that wrapper div, finally, and again in css, make the wrapper div as hight as the form. I didn't try it out, so no warranty ; ]